# Linking fields in from between different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This question is related to: [How to link form after creating rails join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313872/how-to-link-form-after-creating-rails-join-table)

I Had a products model, with a categories field, however needed each category in individual rows rather than the comma separated rows they were in. So I created a Category and ProductCategory model, and added all appropriate associations.

How do I link up the categories field from the old products model to the new Category table so that when a user enter a new product and adds the category, it will save to the category table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great Railscast on setting up accepts_nested_attributes_for it should be just what you are looking for.  I would do you a better service by just telling you to watch it, rather than replicate code.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1