# CreateJoinTable migration table naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following migration:

> rails g migration CreateJoinTableQuestionTag question tag

```
class CreateJoinTableQuestionTag < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :questions, :tags do |t|
      t.index [:question_id, :tag_id]
      t.index [:tag_id, :question_id]
    end
  end
end
```

When i run rake:db:migrate it creates this in **schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "questions_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "question_id", null: false
    t.integer "tag_id",      null: false
  end

  add_index "questions_tags", ["question_id", "tag_id"], name: "index_questions_tags_on_question_id_and_tag_id"
  add_index "questions_tags", ["tag_id", "question_id"], name: "index_questions_tags_on_tag_id_and_question_id"
```

In the comand line:

```
QuestionTag.first
  QuestionTag Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "question_tags".* FROM "question_tags"  ORDER BY "question_tags"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: question_tags: SELECT  "question_tags".* FROM "question_tags"  ORDER BY "question_tags"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: question_tags: SELECT
```

Shouldn't this migration create a question_tags table instead of questions_tags?

Comment: `create_join_table :question, :tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the expected.

You'll need to rename your model `QuestionTag` to `QuestionsTag`.

[This question explain the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590469/rails-naming-convention-for-join-table)

Comment: isn't it `QuestionsTags` ?

Comment: No @jesusjjf. Rails pluralize the model names to find the respective database table. So, `QuestionTag` becomes `question_tags` table's name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create a join table:

1. [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many): in this case your join table has the right schema, but you don't have a model for it.
2. you have a model for your join table and you use the `has_many trough:` construct. In this case you can simply `rails g model QuestionTag` and add the two `belongs_to` for the models you want to join together.