# ActiveRecord: Uninitialze constant exception when define many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I have a model named `Post` and a model named `Category`. Relationship between `Post` and `Category` is many-to-many. So I create a join table as following:

```
create_table :categories_posts do |t|
  t.integer :post_id, index: true
  t.integer :category_id, index: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

Here is my model `Post` (file name: `post.rb`)

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_posts
  has_many :categories_posts
end
```

Here is my model `CategoryPost` (file name: `category_post.rb`)

```
class CategoryPost < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "categories_posts"
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

But when I try: `Post.last.categories` or `Post.last.categories_posts` I meet exception:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Post::CategoriesPost

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant Post::CategoriesPost

The *plural* form of `CategoryPost` is `CategoryPosts`, so you should use `category_posts` instead of `categories_posts` when defining associations

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_posts
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_posts
end
```

However, if you want to use `categories_posts`, you can do with by defining `class_name` on the association

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_posts, class_name: "CategoryPost"
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_posts
end
```

Comment: thanks. It works. The thing I don't understand is: I use `categories_posts` because it follows rails convention. why it doesn't work ? thanks.

Comment: the join table I also use `categories_posts`

Comment: @TrầnKimDự There is no convention when defining a third model for `has_many :through`. It should be a correct plural form when defining associations. You can check in console with `"CategoryPost".pluralize`

Comment: I have read at this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590469/rails-naming-convention-for-join-table`

Comment: So it looks like if I follow this convention for defining relationship, I must manually set class name or table name in model, right.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự That convention is for *HABTM* association not for `has_many :through`

Comment: so in case I need `accepts_nested_attributes` I will define `accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories_posts`, right? and when inserting, the attributes should be: `categories_posts_attributes`? thanks.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Yes, thats right. Please accept my answer :)

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories_posts` I have defined this. but when I run, I meet following exception, do you know why: `ArgumentError (No association found for name `categories_posts'. Has it been defined yet?):`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149873/discussion-between-pavan-and-trn-kim-d).

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Let me know when you are available, we can discuss the issue in the chat and close this :)

Comment: thanks. I can resolve by myself :D thanks so much for supporting me.